# Add the original requested URL to the rewrite rule?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress, url

Working with our hosting provider, they've added an nginx rule to help us block access to files within a particular folder. Basically, if the user is logged into the WordPress site, it gives them access to the file. Otherwise, it will redirect them to the login URL of `https://www.example.com/login/`

This is what is currently implemented: https://gist.github.com/Garconis/6be796b51994c79010cb0c3a3cfedd86

```
set $bar 0;
set $becue 0;
if ( $request_uri ~* "wp-content/uploads/private" ) {
    set $bar 1;
} 
if ($http_cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $becue 1;
}
set $barbecue "$bar:$becue";
if ($barbecue = "1:0") {
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.example.com/login/;
}
```

However, I'd like to update the `rewrite` URL, to instead be something like: `https://www.example.com/login?redirect_to=https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/private/super-secret-brochure.pdf`

This way, WordPress will automatically redirect the user back to the file they tried to access, once they log in.

**However, how do I properly update the rewrite, so that it includes the original URL that was trying to be accessed?**

Is it as simple as:

```
rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.example.com/login?redirect_to=https://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I haven't tried that version of the `rewrite` yet. My hosting provider will only implement the rule that I provide... without providing support/help with it. So I wanted help with knowing the best method, before I provided a "solution" to my host.

Comment: Do you not have any control of the server configuration?!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. While it's not shared hosting, there is also no configuration available on our end. But the hosting provider is able to add/adjust the nginx rule on their end for us.